# Issue in passing an xml to jquery script

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I am trying to read an xml from local path using bufferedReader in jsp and trying the pass the xml to a jquery script as below

```
 <%
        StringBuffer xmlStrBuff = new StringBuffer();
        String  xmlStr = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\ROOT\\xml\\test.xml"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                xmlStrBuff.append(line);
            }
            xmlStr = xmlStrBuff.toString();

        }
        catch ( IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    %>

      <script>
        var apiXMLStr = <%="'"+xmlStr+"';"%>
        alert(apiXMLStr);      
       $(document).ready(function(){
        parseXML(apiXMLStr);

      });

    </script>
```

The problem lies in script alert is not showing me the xml and this script is not making a call to parseXML

```
 var apiXMLStr = <%="'"+xmlStr+"';"%>
            alert(apiXMLStr);
```

parseXML  makes a call to apcpage.js which has the below code :

```
  function parseXML(xml){
     alert('parseXML');
     var xmlObj = $(xml);
     apcXmlData=xmlObj;
     if(xmlObj.find('api').length > 0){ 
       xmlObj.find('api').each(function(i){
          var apiName = $(this).attr('name');      
          var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'apiName', value:apiName});
          $("#method_list").append($ctrl).append(apiName);                
       });
     }
```

The xml file is xmlStr output is

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><apis xmlns:xsi=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\'>    <api name="getFieldType" requesttype ="GET">         <url>/fieldtype/</url>                <parameters>             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=textbox&fieldId=8668376496495]]></parameter>             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=number&fieldId=93468613046610]]></parameter>             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=multiline&fieldId=1367537832000]]></parameter>          </parameters>    </api>            </apis>
```

Comment: Did you check line breaks or special semi colons in xml string. They can corrupt your javascript variable

Comment: @arunes i have added the xml that  i got  after doing replaceAll

Comment: You may escape your string (the loaded xml content) before including it as a Javascript string. Use something like `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` from Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html. Depending on your stack with the JSPs, you may have a tag that does this (spring for example).

Answer (score 0):

Works using $.parseXML. Demo runs 2 cases one with and one without the extra parser. The one without fails

http://jsfiddle.net/bUDv3/

Also might trim the xml , when I copied from above there was an extra line break at end. Might account for alert not firing. Are you seeing any errors in a console?