# how to read the object value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to read the object value in jquery but if am trying to use text function it shows me blank.The code is as below :

```
var param = $(this).find('parameter');

                  if(param.attr('pathvar')){
                    var pathvar=param.attr('pathvar');
                    url=url+'/'+pathvar
                    alert(url);
                  }
                  var numLow = 0;
                  var numHigh = (param.length-1);                  
                  var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1;
                  var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);   
                      alert(numRand); 
                      alert("here");  
                      alert(param);   
                  var selParamVal = param.eq((numRand)).text();
                   alert(param.eq((numRand)).text());
makeAPIRequest(selParamVal,requestType,url);                                 
                }
          });

        } 
    }  

function makeAPIRequest(reqjson,reqType,url){
    var json = JSON.stringify(reqjson); 

    $.ajax({
         url:url,    
         type:reqType,
         processData: false,  
         contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data:reqjson,
         headers:{sm_user:'999999300'},
         success:function(data){
           var resp = JSON.stringify(data);
           var textarea = jQuery('#responseEl');
           textarea.text(resp);  
        },
       error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            var textarea = jQuery('#responseEl');
            textarea.text(jqXHR.responseText);
     }
    });

  }
```

The selParamVal is blank.And if even if i add numRand as [numRand] it does not make an ajax call
Trying to read this xml :I am able to get upto url but fails in parameter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apis xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <api name="getFieldType" requesttype ="GET">
         <url>/fieldtype/</url>       
         <parameters>
             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=textbox&fieldId=8668376496495]]></parameter>
             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=number&fieldId=93468613046610]]></parameter>
             <parameter><![CDATA[fieldtype=multiline&fieldId=1367537832000]]></parameter>
          </parameters>
    </api>
</apis>
```

Comment: can you show your console.log(param); ...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528990/issue-in-passing-an-xml-to-jquery-script has the html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this

```
$(this).find('parameter');
```

It is neither an `identifier` nor a `class selector`, or an `element name`

Changes it to appropriate selector. Like the attribute below will select class parameter

```
$(this).find('.parameter');
```

---

**Update:**  I got your code working. The problem seems to be when `$(this)` was not referencing to the xml data.

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2YUgk/)

Comment: parameter is the node in my xml

Comment: @user1195292, you should specify that in your question. I got the wrong idea

Comment: i have added the xml for reference pls help me out.

Comment: @user1195292, I think I solved your problem. Check the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, try adding dataType:"xml", eg:

```
$.ajax({
     url:url,    
     type:reqType,
     processData: false,  
     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data:reqjson,
     headers:{sm_user:'999999300'},

     dataType:"xml", // add this!
     ...
```

and see if works.

If not, then I think you might need to get the selParamVal with this:

```
var selParamVal = param.eq(numRand).html();
```

what you'll get from that is something like this: "", so you just need to parse out the "

Also, I notice this code:

```
var param = $(xml).find('parameter'); // this returns an array of parameters
if(param.attr('pathvar')){            // so this line will always be false
  var pathvar=param.attr('pathvar');
  rl=url+'/'+pathvar
  alert(url);
}
```

You'll need something like this instead:

```
var param = $(xml).find('parameter');
param.each(function(i, parameter) {
  if (parameter.attr('pathvar')) {
    var pathvar=param.attr('pathvar');
    rl=url+'/'+pathvar;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: by the way, I'm assuming your "$(this)" in "$(this).find('parameter');" is the xml content returned from the server